# Maximizing with an assumption

Tags: maximum

I want to maximize an expression assuming `p` is between zero and one. What should I do?

```
z = Re[N[Sqrt[p] Cos[θ1] Cos[θ] + Sqrt[1 - p] E^(I(ϕ + ϕ1)) (Sin[θ]) Sin[θ1]]]; 
λ = Maximize[z, {θ, p, θ1, ϕ1, ϕ}];
```

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
z = Re[N[Sqrt[p] Cos[\[Theta]1] Cos[\[Theta]] +
Sqrt[1 -p] E^(I (\[Phi] + \[Phi]1)) (Sin[\[Theta]]) Sin[\[Theta]1]]];
\[Lambda] = Maximize[z,p >= 0 && p <= 1, {\[Theta], p, \[Theta]1, \[Phi]1, \[Phi]}]
```

does the job, producing

> {1., {[Theta] -> -9.04986*10^-9, 
>     p -> 1., [Theta]1 -> -9.74328*10^-9, [Phi]1 -> 
>      0.430937, [Phi] -> -1.04225}}